# MacBook keyboard and mouse hardware do not work on ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, hardware, mac, macbook-pro

I booted ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on my MacBook Pro 15.2 but the built-in keyboard and mousepad hardware do not work. Using Linux 5.15.0-67-generic. Anyone know how I can activate the built-in keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Couple of things. 1. 5.15 would be a partial kernel number not a version of Ubuntu. 2. The keyboard and mouse of that machine should be Bluetooth if memory serves. So have you connected them via Bluetooth?

Comment: You mean the native keyboard and mousepad on the laptop are linked with Bluetooth? That would be a first for me

Comment: Usually on MAC yes.

Comment: Sure on MAC, but a laptop keyboard is directly connected to the motherboard?

Comment: You should edit the question and add that bit. That you are using the built in keyboard.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your answers.